# How to create manifest file for an app that needs only one java file as a service?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a simple background app that extends a subclass of the system service, the resource of the original file (that is being extended) lays out general instructions on how to declare it as a service in the manifest file:

```
   <service>
      android:name=".MyCustom"
      android:exported="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
      android:label="@string/my_custom_label" >
 
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.service.targetservice" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.service.targetservice"
          android:resource="@xml/my_custom" />
  </service>
```

But I can't figure out what to put inside in the `<application>` tag. The file `MyCustom` is the single java file in the entire project.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All of that goes in the application tag.  The application tag has all services, activities, and broadcast receivers inside it.